# Maven- No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a springboot project I built with Spring Tools Suite.  I get the following error when I execute `$mvn spring-boot:run`

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 14.0 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 21.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.032 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-15T17:46:50-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/admin/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]     http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException`
```

Heres my pom.xml plugin

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>--spring.profiles.active=dev</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I tried the jhipster plugin above and no change in the error.

Comment: I faced the same issue in Mac. 
I was able to fix it by changing default java from 13 to 8.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot for application, forgetting to add

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
```

can cause this issue, as well as missing these lines

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: what if this is a child module and it actually has a parent?

Comment: @DylanCzenski Per another answer lower down, try: `mvn org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:run`

Comment: @DylanCzenski I have the same situation and cant add the parent mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 262):

If you are running the

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

from the command line, make sure you are in the directory that contains the *pom.xml* file. Otherwise, you will run into the *No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups* error.

Comment: Correct Answer. I was facing this issue while using Google Cloud Shell while creating Spring Boot app with Kotlin. This answer helps me to resolve the mentioned issue.

Comment: Its `mvn spring-boot:run` not `mvn springboot:run`

Comment: OMG, wrong directory answer saves the day!

Answer (score 71):

If you don't want to use

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>(...)</version>
</parent>
```

as the parent POM, you may use

```
mvn org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:run
```

instead.

Answer (score 30):

Typos are a possible reason for this error.

Be sure to check you wrote `spring-boot` and not e.g. `springboot` or `sprint-boot` or `springbok` or whatever.

Also check the ordering : use `spring-boot:run` and not `run:spring-boot`.

Answer (score 14):

You might want to add the following to your pom and try compiling

```
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Why would this be happening? I am on a corporate network that does not allow accessing external repos, our internal mirror seems to have the right JARs but what would have made them bad?

Answer (score 9):

You should run the `$ mvn spring-boot:run` from the folder where your `pom.xml` file is located and refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33602837/4918021

Answer (score 9):

Use `mvn spring-boot:run`.
No `mvn sprint-boot:run`
Error Writing.

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score 6):

Adding spring-boot-maven-plugin in the build resolved it in my case

```
<build>
    <finalName>mysample-web</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This was my situation. It was working before, then I commented that part ( thinking of commenting something else ) and all of the sudden my app stop working.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure pom.xml exist in the directory, when using the mvn spring-boot:run command.
No need to add any thing in the pom.xml file.

Comment: I mean.. the error literally says that something is missing when executing this command, hence something has to be added to the POM.

Comment: For me, I added nothing, just needed to be in the project folder on terminal before executing the command.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the full plugin name (with groupId) like described in [Bartosz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873826/555366), you could add

```
<pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.springframework.boot</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

to your .m2/settings.xml.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this error after updating my spring boot in pom.xml and running it in Eclipse.

The source of the error is that the run configuration was set to offline, thus it couldn't download plugins on run.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my maven variable environment was M2_HOME,
so I've changed to MAVEN_HOME and worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @vfranca9.  Perhaps some explanation would make your answer more clear.  By, "in my case" do you mean that you were getting the same error message in response to the same command?