# Spring Boot: Controller does nothing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a Boot/MVC project. When I start Tomcat, the pages displays perfectly fine, but when I try to add anything with my `ModelAndView` object, nothing appears on the page. Not even a `System.out.println("anything")` will show on the console.

Here is Application.java

```
package com.markham.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

IndexController.java:

```
package com.markham.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager em;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        TypedQuery<User> query1 = em.createNamedQuery("User.getAllUsers", User.class);
        users = query1.getResultList();
        System.out.println("HERE'S THE THING---" + users); //This doesn't even print
        view.addObject("users", users);
        return view;
    }

}
```

How can I make it so my controller works with my index.jsp - the default page?

If you need more code, just ask and I will supply it.

EDIT:

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 `http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">`
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spring Boot Web Application</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Web Application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://example

spring.datasource.username = example
spring.datasource.password = example

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Edit #2: This is the url I'm accessing `http://localhost:8080/BootApp/`

Here are the logs:

```
  Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BootApp' did not find a matching property.
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Aug 18 2015 11:38:37 UTC
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.26.0
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.11.3
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/ben/Documents/workspace/rabbitmq/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/ben/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/ben/Documents/workspace/rabbitmq/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/ben/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/ben/Documents/workspace/rabbitmq/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/ben/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/endorsed
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/ben/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 891 ms
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = samsung Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "-1" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = samsung Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "-1" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
INFO: Name = samsung Ignoring unknown property: value of "true" for "spring.datasource.testOnBorrow" property
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
INFO: Name = samsung Ignoring unknown property: value of "SELECT 1" for "spring.datasource.validationQuery" property
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
INFO: Name = samsung Ignoring unknown property: value of "true" for "autoReconnect" property
Mar 16, 2016 6:13:57 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 16, 2016 6:14:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = samsung Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "-1" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
Mar 16, 2016 6:14:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = samsung Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "-1" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
Mar 16, 2016 6:14:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
INFO: Name = samsung Ignoring unknown property: value of "true" for "spring.datasource.testOnBorrow" property
Mar 16, 2016 6:14:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
INFO: Name = samsung Ignoring unknown property: value of "SELECT 1" for "spring.datasource.validationQuery" property
Mar 16, 2016 6:14:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
INFO: Name = samsung Ignoring unknown property: value of "true" for "autoReconnect" property
Mar 16, 2016 6:14:01 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 16, 2016 6:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@60111f5c]
Mar 16, 2016 6:14:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 16, 2016 6:14:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 16, 2016 6:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3713 ms
```

EDIT #3 (thanks for the help everyone): After doing `mvn spring-boot:run`, this error appears:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/ben/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Comment: How are you executing the controller? What url you are forming to access it?

Comment: @BhushanBhangale the default `localhost:8080/BootApp/`

Comment: @bmarkham do you run it as a spring boot (embedded tomcat) ? post your pom.xml and application.properties also

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan Edited my post

Comment: try just `localhost:8080`, also I think you might need `@RequestMapping()` for the controller too.

Comment: do you run it as a java app (will use embedded tomcat) or do you deploy to tomcat server ?

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan I hit run on Tomcat on Eclipse and I go to a browser and type in the url

Comment: try mvn spring-boot:run and use localhost:8080

Comment: Or just run the `Application` class. There's a reason it has a `main` method.

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan I got an error on the command `No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups`

Comment: Just as reminder, displaying the page works perfectly fine, it's just the controller does nothing.

Comment: Please show the url you try to access and the logs.

Comment: @bmarkham, if my guess is correct tomcat serves the default page index.jsp - it is not your controller that returns the view.

Comment: @shazin Edited the post

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan Ahhhh that would actually make sense

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan yes, I changed `index.jsp` to `welcome.jsp` and I'm get a `404 error`

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan sorry for a barrage of comments... but how do I override that in Spring Boot?

Comment: the issue is this is not being run as a spring boot  app. got the directory where you have this project. in the command prompt use mvn spring-boot:run - your pom already has this plugin. and post the terminal/command prompt output. and BTW in spring boot app the views are located in src/main/resources/templates

Comment: try to change requestMapping  @RequestMapping(value = "/BootApp/", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: @Bhavesh Still have `404`.

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan I posted to output. This appears when I do it in Eclipse and terminal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855864/maven-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-spring-boot-in-the-current-project-and-in-th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I've finally gotten it to work thanks to pretty much everyone who helped.

@BalajiKrishnan 's was correct when I wasn't running it as a Spring Boot app. I changed it from a jar to war and used `mvn spring-boot:run` and now it runs as a Spring Boot app. [BalajiKrishnan's Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855864/maven-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-spring-boot-in-the-current-project-and-in-th)

However, I was still getting `404 errors` and used @shazin 's answer to change my `application.properties` the way he posted. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36031459/9300379)

Still was getting `404 errors` so I changed my url from `localhost:8080/BootApp/` to just `localhost:8080` just like @EpicPandaForce suggested in the comments.

And I changed I used `ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("index");`, just like @shazin suggested.

Thank you to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 1):

Your `ModelAndView` doesn't say which file it wants to access

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index() {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("index"); // This line
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    TypedQuery<User> query1 = em.createNamedQuery("User.getAllUsers", User.class);
    users = query1.getResultList();
    System.out.println("HERE'S THE THING---" + users); //This doesn't even print
    view.addObject("users", users);
    return view;
}
```

Your `application.properties` doesn't have the MVC View Resolver configurations.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=<Path To Jsp>
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

First of all make those changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem :(. I appreciate the answer tho.

Answer (score 1):

Issue :  you are attempting to run SpringBoot app in an external server and not in the embedded tomcat.

---

**Running as spring boot in embedded container:**
To run as spring boot use `mvn spring-boot:run` command in directory containing the pom.xml. I suggest you go through https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ getting started guide.

---

**Deploying to external server**
If you want to deploy in external server, change the packaging from jar to war and deploy the war file. Reference for deploying to WAS https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

Comment: I also changed from jar to war file and it works... Kind of.. I get a `404 error` message but it's actually from Spring Boot now. Here's the error. `There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). /src/main/resources/templates/index.jsp` That is the correct path to my jsp

Answer (score 1):

change `@RestController` with `@Controller` in IndexController.class

and add wiew page mame `ModelAndView` object

```
ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("index.jsp");
```

and index.jsp `spring boot default location src/main/webapp`

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to redirect your request into the specific page. You need to pass this page name as a parameter while creating **ModelAndView** object.

Example: If you want to redirect your request to the `welcome.jsp` page then you can create **ModelAndView** like following:

```
ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("welcome.jsp");
//code as per your requirement 
return view;
```

And you need following dependency in your **pom.xml** file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note: I am assuming your `welcome.jsp` page is in following package:

```
src/main/webapp
```

You can find simple demo application [here](https://github.com/yubarajkalathoki/spring-boot-jsp-demo).

Comment: @bmarkham  I works correctly. Can you let me know what error did you get?