# "No plugin found for prefix ''spring-root' in the current project error after I install two updates in STS

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am using Spring Tool Suite. I check out demo projects in STS. It works fine without any problem before I installed updates in STS today.

I have checked this post, but its solution ([Maven- No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855864/maven-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-spring-boot-in-the-current-project-and-in-th)) is not working for me.

The steps to reproduce my bug：

1. In STS, in "File" -> "New" -> "Import Spring Getting Started Content", then check out "Building a RESTful Web Service" this project.
2. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
   I go to my project folder, type 'mvnw spring-root:run' (I am using Windows). Then got following error.
3. I do not if this bug related to I installed two updated in STS today, because today STS told me that I have two updates to install, then I just installed.

[image]

Update: Sorry, I have a typo. I type 'mvnw spring-boot:run', now it gives this error: **[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project gs-rest-service: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start -> [Help 1]**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your maven command.
Use `spring-boot` with a `b` not `spring-root`.

Comment: You are correct. I had a typo. But I got another error. Could you see my updated post?

Comment: If you have a different question then ask it in a separate question. Better yet, search for an existing answer.

Comment: All right. Anyway, you solved my problem which I asked here. I will ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add  spring-boot-maven-plugin in to `pom.xml`and try it, the build resolved it in my case.

```
<build>
    <finalName>mysample-web</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I think this is deprecated by now.