# No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot'

Tags: spring, maven

I am getting below error

```
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (/root/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (/root/.m2/repository)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 26.391 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-21T04:57:47+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/106M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/root/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/root/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
```

Please suggest if I need to make any correction in my pom.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven- No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855864/maven-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-spring-boot-in-the-current-project-and-in-th)

Comment: can you post your `pom.xml` file

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/sandeeptest321/pom.xml This is my file.

Comment: I faced the same issue in Mac. I was able to fix it by changing default java from 13 to 8.

Answer (score 2):

go to where your **pom.xml**  in terminal
and use command

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```