# Not plugin found for prefix "spring-boot" & No goals specified - Maven Project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I've executed the command >mvn clean boot-spring:run, but the build fails because of the next error:
"No plugin found for prefix 'boot-spring' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local ], spring-releases https://repo.spring.io/libs-release, central ]

In addition, if I write >mvn -X or >mvn -e, it launchs the error message:

"No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or [:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: (...)"
and the shows a list of names (verify, install, process-sources, etc.).

Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>MyWeb</groupId>
<artifactId>myweb</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <swagger.version>2.8.0</swagger.version>

    <deploy>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</deploy>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>${encoding}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${encoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       <project.resources.sourceEncoding>${encoding}</project.resources.sourceEncoding>         
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot ====================================== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Database ====================================== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Swagger ====================================== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ================ TEST ================== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<!-- ================ TEST extensions================== -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*FunctionalTesting</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855864/maven-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-spring-boot-in-the-current-project-and-in-th

Comment: No, since I've already tried with that post solutions and, in addition, I specify my full pom and also make reference to the Maven goals problem, which that post doesn't