# How can I to get a simple Hello World App to work in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Good day.

I am on the second video of the comprehensive KK JavaTutorials for Spring Boot on Youtube.

I have uploaded my code to Git Hub at https://github.com/ishonowo/HelloWorldSpringBoot.

The code should print Hello Nigeria. in the browser once it is working.

I get the error below instead.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication    at
>   com.infotech.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp.main(HelloWorldSpringBootApp.java:10)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 1 more

I have checked and the class org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication is in the Maven jars.

Please assist.

Thanks.

Comment: I imported the project into Eclipse and run it from there as Spring Boot App and it worked fine so you probably run it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

to your `pom.xml` and run your application with `mvn spring-boot:run`. I was able to print `Hello Nigeria` when I visited `/`.

Comment: See below the error I get when trying to run project.

Comment: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\doctor\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\doctor\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

Comment: I used  mvn spring-boot:run -e -X

Comment: You might be forgetting to set the parent of your project. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855864/maven-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-spring-boot-in-the-current-project-and-in-th

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
 at com.infotech.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp.main(HelloWorldSpringBootApp.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more

Comment: <build>
    <finalName>mysample-web</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to delete the .m2 folder and allow Maven to re-download the jars.